# My program works fine in IDLE and PyScripter, but not in PowerShell and command line

Tags: powershell, python-3.x, python-idle

This seems like a really basic question, but I wasn't able to find the solution anywhere, so here it goes:

I'm writing a small program, mostly for practice, that does difefrent things, depending on my input, like so:

```
while True:
    switch = input('a, b or c:')

    if switch == "a":
        print("In command line and Powershell...")
    elif switch == "b":
        print("...these lines will never run.")
    elif switch == "c":
        print("Neither will this one, no matter what my input(switch) is.")
    else:
         print("meh...")
                 break
```

If I run my code in IDLE or PyScripter interpreter it works fine, but when I run it in the command line or in PowerShell, no matter what my input is, the "else" line gets executed every time.

Comment: Could it be end of line parsing by OS vs. the interpreter of the IDE?

Comment: Try `print(repr(switch))` to see exactly what you're getting out of it?

Comment: I'm getting a string, but with a '\r' at the end of it, like in     'a\r'. I'm new to python, I've looked it up but I'm still not sure what this does or how to fix it. Was anyone able to run this little script in PowerShell without any problems?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you get a carriage return at the end, are you running this on Windows, perhaps. On Unix it works well. The workaround is to make sure to strip any whitespace:

```
switch = input('a, b or c:').strip()
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: This worked, thank you. And yey, I'm running this on Windows.

Comment: @gorjupdomen: This bug was in 3.2, but fixed in 3.2.1, btw. So you can upgrade to the latest 3.2, and it will work as well. http://bugs.python.org/issue11272