# Error evaluating user input string in python

Tags: python, powershell, python-3.x, notepad++, python-idle

I am using notepad++ and windows powershell for editing and executing python 3.2 programs.
Here are two case

1. Case 1

   ```
   w = 'a'
   u = 'a'
   print (u == w)
   ```

   OUTPUT: `True`
2. Case 2

   ```
   w = "a"
   u = input('enter string ') #user enters a
   print (u == w)
   ```

   OUTPUT: `False`

I can't figure out what's causing this error.
The OUTPUT for both the cases is True in IDLE but it doesn't match in case of notepad++ and powershell combination. 
Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: can you print u in case 2, and see what it is in fact?

Comment: How are you executing these scripts from notepad++/powershell?

Comment: the value of u returned is a. @HenryH save the file from notepad++ then use powersheel commands to execute those files >python xxx.py

Comment: Got it figured. Theres a bug in python 3.2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769364/my-program-works-fine-in-idle-and-pyscripter-but-not-in-powershell-and-command?rq=1